How is PID 1 made special and unkillable?
Using docker, I recently found that PID 1 is by default unkillable by SIGTERM.  Yet you can still catch SIGTERM in PID 1 if you setup a handler in the process.  So this doesn't seem to be the case of the kernel just masking SIGTERM for PID 1.
How is this implemented?  How does the process as PID 1 have the default SIGTERM handler be a noop?

I misread the google search result as "unlikeable!"

Poking in kernel sources, it looks like SIG_DFL is actually just the value 0 and doesn't point to any "default" code that might come from libc.  Same with SIG_IGN -- it's value is 1.
So the default handler is actually in kernel space, not user space. So the kernel must have a special case for pid 1 in this default handler.
References:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625896/where-is-the-code-for-default-signal-handler-in-elf-binary

This might be the flag that all PID 1 signals receive:
264  #define SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE   0x00000040 /* for init: ignore fatal signals */

The only place where it's set seems to be here:
1460  if (is_child_reaper(pid)) {
1461      ns_of_pid(pid)->child_reaper = p;
1462      p->signal->flags |= SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE;
1463  }

is_child_reaper() apparently confirms that the pid of the new process equals 1.
And probably here:
2832  /*
2833   * Global init gets no signals it doesn't want.
2834   * Container-init gets no signals it doesn't want from same
2835   * container.
2836   *
2837   * Note that if global/container-init sees a sig_kernel_only()
2838   * signal here, the signal must have been generated internally
2839   * or must have come from an ancestor namespace. In either
2840   * case, the signal cannot be dropped.
2841   */
2842  if (unlikely(signal->flags & SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE) &&
2843          !sig_kernel_only(signr))
2844      continue;

it executes continue which doesn't let it execute the default action (in case of PID 1).
